# why br not save in text file and html file in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]I am facing one problem .I am getting data from server and show it on screen .it look good 
Having br tag .
It look like that
My name is ksdhfk (having br tag) 
hello ndfjsdf 
But when i have  in text file or html file 
it show 
My name is ksdhfk (without having br tag) hello ndfjsdf .where is br tag goes..?

But I save this file on html or text .
It look like this.

**Â (Note: In open court at.)Â THE COURT: I'm going to reserve counsel whether or not this will go into evidence at this stage. The Court wants to do a little additional research with regard to the matter.Â @DFATTY1: Thank you. Â THE COURT: Are we ready to bring the jury back in? Did enough {iing} else, counsel.Â @PLFATTY1: No, Your Honor.Â THE COURT: Okay. Can you keep -- is this an !d1W=!e1W=!f1W>!g1W>!h1W>!i1W?!j1W?!k1W?!l1W?!m1W@!n1W@!o1W@!p1WA!q1WA!r1WA!s1WB!t1WB!u1WB!v1WB!w1WC!x1WC!y2WC!{1WC!|1WD!}1WE!~1WE!1WE!1WE!1WF!1WF!2WF!1WG!1WG!1WG!1WG!1WH!1WH!1WH!1WH!1WI!1WJ!1WJ!1WJ!1WJ!1WK!1WK!1WK!1WL!1WL!1WL!1WM!1WM!1WM!1WM!1WM!1WM!1WN!1WO!1WO!1WO!1WO!1WP!1WP!1WP!1WP!1WQ!1WQ!1WQ.Â THE COURT: Okay. I'll reserve ruling with regard to that matter, but we're ready to proceed.Â @PLFATTY1: Yes, Your Honor. Â THE COURT: Okay the front page that said the Exhibit Number on it, but yes, we have.Â THE COURT: This one in the back which I think you gave me separate says L--2 A.Â @DFATTY1: That's the front page and they're beats stamped one through 14. Cpz)pz^3tkP//PxP/D/PÂ `1/PxgW'p//((51((((/`1P.{x^~+qq~~~`(@~%5Â (Note: Jury present.) pz33)D)F3=P//PxP/D/PÂ` 1/PxgW'p//**51****/`1P.{tx^hM*h^D)D)I working? C3)D)Fn2[=P//PxP/D/PÂ` 1/PxgW'p//,,51,,,,/`1P.{x^hh^D)D)I started )npz33)D)F3r6=P//PxP/D/PÂ` 1/PxgW'p////51/////`1P.{x^h.h^D)D)a +Cpz%)pz^--t)-CX^D)D)x'q%/1$(/@//PltkD)(*D)3%^D)D)(8Â Â X/tko`/XBÂ g@nff/ff@`1`W/H/Sm8m8%66X/`mSmhm8%%n8%new Cpz%)pz^--4_-CX^D)D)x'q%/3$L/@//PltkD)(*D)3%^D)D)/f3g351f3f3g3f3/`1.{file. )npz33)D)F3R=P//PxP/D/PÂ `1/PxgW'p//55515555/`1P.{x^hY4h^D)D)I +Cpz%)pz(}u%^--r-CX^D)D)x'q%/7$@!/@//PltkD)(*D)3%^D)D)/77875177778777/`1.{just started npz33)D)F3R=P//PxP/D/PÂ` 1/PxgW'p//99519999/`1P.{(x^h(8h^D)D)a +Cpz%)pz(}u%^--4s-CX^D)D)x'q%/x;$x/@//PltkD)(*D)3%^D)D)/W;X;51W;W;X;W;/`1.{new Cpz%)pz(}u%^--$V-CX^D)D)x'q%/=$(/@//PltkD)(*D)3%^D)D)(8Â Â X/tk;`/XBÂ g@nff/ff@`1`W/H/Sm8m8%AAX/`mSmhm8%%n8%file. For 33)D)F3=P//PxP/D/PÂ `1/PxgW'p//6?7?516?6?7?6?/`1P.{$x^h>h^D)D)some Cpz%)pz(}u%^--M-CX^D)D)x'q%/@$(/@//PltkD)(*D)3%^D)D)(8Â Â X/tk?`/XBÂ g@nff/ff@`1`W/H/Sm8m8%EEX/`mSmhm8%%n8%reason once )npz33)D)F3=P//PxP/D/PÂ `1/PxgW'p//BB51BBBB/`1P.{4x^hjBh^D)D)you CpzJ8)pz(Cn^---CX^D)D)x'q%/D$(/@//PtkD)(*D)3%^D)D)(8Â Â X/tkD`/XBÂ g@ff/ff@`1`W/H/Sm8m8%IIX/`mSmhm8%%n8%**

[image]

I have div and i save like that

```
function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
{

   var isappend= window.localStorage.getItem("isAppendButtonClick");
   if(isappend=='true'){
    console.log(result+"************naveen***************");
    $('#realTimeContents' ).append('<br>'+'<p>'+result+'</p>'+'</br>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little be clearer with your question? I think I get it but can you show some source code or an example?

Comment: you using any scripting language like php,asp.net etc for getting data from server ?

Comment: post some more description. What you have tried?

Comment: any update solution..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem in saving the text file..please save the file .you save your file using .html..

Like that

```
fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                               writer.seek(writer.length);

                               writer.write($('#realTimeContents').html());
                           }, fail);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
    function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
{

   var isappend= window.localStorage.getItem("isAppendButtonClick");
   if(isappend=='true'){
    console.log(result+"************naveen***************");
    $('#realTimeContents' ).append('<br><p>'+result+'</p><br>');
  }
}
```

Comment: text file and append file show in same line without changing the line

Comment: No i save data of what i see in simulator then read that data ..But during reading it show in single line

Comment: what is in the result, is it regular html?

Comment: when save it is on same line ..i think there is problem in saving .I just dave what where in that div like this?writer.write($('#realTimeContents').text();